# Determine the currently used memory inside a workingset

Tags: .net, winapi, memory-management

I'm working with memory mapped files to deal with many large files that need to be open at the same time. The files contain volume data for image processing. The contents of the files are sometimes accessed randomly, sometimes sequentially (depending on the algorithm that is running on the data). Each volume is backed by one memory mapped file and the system page file should not be involved.

I encountered one problem with memory mapped files. While I'm processing the data the memory consumption grows but the memory manager keeps doing nothing to balance the memory situation. Only when the whole physical memory is used you can suddenly see that the manager is paging the memory to the memory mapped files. But: While this is happening I'm still reading/writing more data so that the whole application or even the whole system is stalled.

I haven't found a way to control the system paging behavior, so I decided to include my own memory management (something like a GC). I store an index to the touched memory locations (in multiples of the slices contained in the volume), and I also store an access count and the last access time. My memory manager runs in a background thread and looks for low and high memory conditions to react accordingly. If the memory condition is low, the manager first blocks everyone from processing new data. Then the used memory is sorted and checked which is to oldest. Then the memory is beginning to unmap the data with `FlushViewOfFile`.

Until here everything works, but the problem is that the memory does not show any change it simply keeps its low memory condition, so that the memory manager runs again and again.
What helped was calling `EmptyWorkingSet`, but I doubt that this is the solution here, since it empties the whole working set for memory that is not in use.

Obviously `QueryMemoryResourceNotification` to query for low or high memory resource conditions are watching over the workingset and since the working set is not emptied that are "firing" the whole time.

Is there any deep documentation for this sort of memory management?

Comment: `FlushViewOfFile` not umap the data, but writing modified pages to the disk

Comment: @RbMm: That is something I'm not quite sure. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-flushviewoffile FlushViewOfFile flushes, but if you want to have it on disk for sure you have to call FlushFIleBuffers. It seems that FlushViewOfFile is only a hint, since it also doesn't wait.

Comment: This sounds to me like you are reinventing the file system cache. Have you tried the whole thing without MemoryMappedFiles and accessing the files directly instead?

Comment: @Steeeve: I thin kthis is an interesting, I haven't done this so far. What prevents me is, that sometimes I need access to the whole data inside a volume. Having a pointer that takes care of all of the read/writes seemed a good idea to me. But you are right, maybe I should also think in different directions.